# Loading Multiband tiff image into OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried loading a 8 band tiff image into OpenCV C++ but when I checked the dimensions of the image it gives me 3 bands of 1500 by 0 pixels. The image is 1500 by 1500 pixles with 8 bands. Is there a place I am going wrong? My code is as below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat Image, Normalized, ImageCopy;
    if (argc != 2){
        cout << "Define Image location" << endl;
    }
    else{
        Image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED|CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    }

    cout <<" Number of bands \t: " << Image.channels() << "\t Image size\t"<< Image.size() << endl;

    //Checking image validity
    if(!Image.data){
        cout << "Invalid image" <<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't think, there's support for images like this in opencv. try to find another tool, that allows you to split it into single channel images.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are out of luck, in `TiffDecoder::readHeader()` there is this:

```
  m_type = CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, photometric > 1 ? 3 : 1);
```

That is, it is using the PHOTOMETRIC tag to set the number of channels to 1 or 3.
For your code to work, you would need it to set the number of channels based on the SAMPLESPERPIXEL tag, but is doesn't. The whole decoder seems to be peppered with the assumption that an image is either grayscale or RGB. Even an RGBA image has its alpha channel discarded.

You could use libtiff directly, using the OpenCV source in grfmt_tiff.cpp as a guide.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to OpenCV C++; could you kindly provide me a sample code or a link for the material so I have look? Thanks.

Comment: The OpenCV source repository is at https://github.com/itseez/opencv. libtiff is at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/libtiff or http://www.libtiff.org/. The latest tiff codec source is in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/imgcodecs/src; although the code excerpt above is from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp

Comment: As I mentioned before I am a beginner in C++ and OpenCV. I am still struggling with the same problem despite some advice above. Now I stumbled on this code: (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/highgui/raster-gdal/raster_io_gdal.html)  which to me looks simple but I do know which libraries the IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL is using because I get an error on it when I use the code. Kindly advice.

Comment: You need OpenCV 3.0.0 to use that